# Block is not getting executed

Tags: ios, block, ios9.2

I have declared the method as follows:

```
- (void)downloadCSVs:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Its body is:

```
- (void)downloadCSVs:(void (^)(void))completion
{
        [[Singleton sharedData] downloadCSVFilesFromServer:<MY_URL>];
}
```

and calling this method as:

```
[self downloadCSVs:^
{
        NSLog(@"Download Completed!");
}];
```

But its after download, it is not executing the NSLog.
Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: you need call completion(); in side downloadCSVs: function implement. Or pass completion block to another function or property an call completion(); when all task is done.

Comment: @A Báo Yes Bao! I did the same and it is working now! Thanks for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block isn't being called as there is no attempt to call it.

The following method accepts the block as a parameter and, in turn, calls `[Singleton downloadCSVFilesFromServer:]` but it does not pass the block to this method and does not call it itself:

```
- (void)downloadCSVs:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [[Singleton sharedData] downloadCSVFilesFromServer:<MY_URL>];
}
```

You need to extend the `[Singleton downloadCSVFilesFromServer:]` method to accept the block parameter and call it when it's complete.

Comment: Thanks for you response. It is working now as I didn't called the block explicitly. I thought it will be called by itself as I have called the method. But can you please explain what did you mean by ---------------You need to extend the [Singleton downloadCSVFilesFromServer:] method to accept the block parameter-------------------------?

Comment: @Developer You need to add the `completion` parameter to that method and have it call it when complete.  I am assuming it's an asynchronous method?

Comment: No its a synchronous method but later I will make it asynchronous. Can you please let me know the syntax of -------------------You need to add the completion parameter to that method----------------. I think I have already added that in the declaration of my method. Can you please check once?

Comment: Something like :`downloadCSVFilesFromServer:(NSURL *)url withCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that code. I think I am still little confused because if you see my method---------------- (void)downloadCSVs:(void (^)(void))completion-------------------, I have added the completion handler so I was expecting that it will be called by itself. And you are suggesting me to put completion handler block to the method which is downloading the CSV. I mean how it is different to putting completion handler in my method. Sorry to bother you. If you want we can discuss over the chat. :-)

Comment: @Developer Well somewhere along the line something has to call `completion()`.  That is best done in the thing that knows when the operation is complete; i.e. the downloader method.

Comment: Yes! I did the same. I have added completion() at the last of my method and it works now. I have accepted and voted up your answer. :-)